# SQL Server Reset Column every Year

Tags: sql-server

Is this possible to do in SQL Server? and If so how would I go about it?

I have a table called Employees which looks like this:

[image]

The Last three Columns are computed Columns made using the following Queries:

Awarded Leave:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
ADD TotalHoursThisYear as 
(
CASE 

WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1,12,31)  THEN 0 

WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,12,31) THEN 8 

WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,12,31) THEN 16

WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,12,31) THEN 24  

WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,12,31) THEN 32 

WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+6,01,01) AND D 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1000,12,31) THEN 40

END 


)
GO
```

TotalHoursThisYear:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
ADD TotalHoursThisYear as CAST 
(
CASE 

WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1,12,31)  THEN 0 + [HoursCarriedForward]  
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,12,31) THEN 8 + [HoursCarriedForward] 
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,12,31) THEN 16 + [HoursCarriedForward] 
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,12,31) THEN 24 + [HoursCarriedForward] 
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,12,31) THEN 32 + [HoursCarriedForward] 
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+6,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1000,12,31) THEN 40 + [HoursCarriedForward] 

END 

+

CASE 
WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(StartDate), 12,31) >= GETDATE() THEN datediff(day, 
[StartDate],datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),(12), 
(31)))/(30.42)*13.33
ELSE [ALCategory]
END AS INT 

)
GO
```

Entitlement Remaining: Same as TotalHoursThisYear just - HoursTaken after HoursCarriedForward.

My Question is, is it possible to set up a trigger or something so at the end of the year (31st December midnight) every year the remaining value in EntitlementRemaing gets added onto the Column HoursCarriedForward and then HoursTaken gets reset to 0.

I should also add, HoursTaken is leftjoined with another table that records holiday requests.

Using this to build an app in asp.net mvc

Comment: Uploading images of your data is not very helpful. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). A trigger is not the right thing here at all. You are talking about creating an end of year process which happens once a year. A trigger fires when something happens to a row in the database.

Comment: Do you want `EntitlementRemaining` to be _added_ to `HoursCarriedForward`, or to replace it? My intuition is the second, as it seems LY `HoursCarriedForward` would be part of the `EntitlementRemaining` calculation.

Comment: @Eric I would like `EntitlementRemaining` to be added to `HoursCarriedForward`. But Yes I can see the problem there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is write a simple stored procedure to make the data modification you're looking for. Just an `UPDATE` statement from the looks of it.

Then use the job scheduling software of choice for your organization (SQL Agent, Control-M, what have you) to have the job run at the end of the year.